# aws upload shows me CredentialsError

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I create file input and submit (name="file).
then connect through `middlewares` like below.

```
globalRouter
  .route("/video")
  .get(getVideo)
  .post(uploadFiles.single("file"), postVideo);
```

And uploadFiles is set to upload AWS.

```
const s3 = new aws.S3({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
  },
});

const multerUploader = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: "practiceguitar",
  acl: "public-read",
});

export const uploadFiles = multer({
  dest: "uploads/",
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10000000,
  },
  storage: multerUploader,
});
```

But it keeps showing error message below.
I set credentials but why it shows me this error?

```
Error: 
    at Error.<anonymous> (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/core-js/internals/wrap-error-constructor-with-cause.js:37:62)
    at new Error (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/core-js/modules/es.error.cause.js:28:43)
    at Request.extractError (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:718:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/hayat/wetube/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
```

Comment: confirm that `process.env.AWS_ID` and `process.env.AWS_SECRET` are set by console.log where you use them

Comment: I also write it directly but still comes 2nd error. Anonymous

Comment: so, if you "write it directly" the first error disappears?

Comment: not familiar with `multer` ... but you do know that `.post(uploadFiles.single("file"), postVideo);` runs `uploadFiles.single("file")` exactly once ever, not every time you `post`

Comment: Are these `express` or `connect` middlewares?

Comment: @Matt express :)